# ListView animation refresh adapter android

Tags: android, listview, animation, adapter

I have a `ListView` with an adapter. When I click on an item on the `ListView`, the adapter is cleared and filled with new content. I want to apply two animations, one when the adapter is cleared (the items are slided to the left when removed from the adapter) and another when the new items are added to the adapter (the new elements are slided to the right).

So what I would like to do when click on an item is something like:

```
listView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_to_left));    
clearAdapter();    
listView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_to_right));    
setItems(newItemList);//Refresh adapter with new items
```

My problem is that only the second animation is shown.

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong or why this is not working?

Thanks.

**Solution**

I've been able to solve it adding an animation listener like this.

```
    Animation animationOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_to_left);
    animationOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            clearAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        listView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_to_right));
                setItems(newList);// update content adapter
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
  listView.startAnimation(animationOut);
```

Would it be a way to show both animation at the same time? While we are clearing the adapter and they are slided to the left, the new content for the list is entered from the right with an animation.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out second animation code(last two lines) and then see , whether first animiations is working. if working then try with adding Thread.sleep for few seconds between first animation and second animation.

Comment: I don't think having a Thread to check whether the first animation has finished is a good approach, there should be a better way.